# HTML/CSS- Font awesome showing as square space

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-awesome

I'm trying to get Font-Awesome (6.2.1) to work but it's only showing up as squares. I dont know if i linked right, because the font awesome link always confuses me.

Does anyone have any suggestions?Its my cart icon

```
#product1 .pro .des .cart{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background-color: #e8f6ea;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #088178;
    border: 1px solid #cce7d0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 10px;
}

 <div class="pro">
                <img src="casa-wacom-2-removebg-preview.png" alt="">
                <div class="des">
                 <span>Wacom</span>
                 <h5>Case para Wacom</h5>
                 <div class="star">
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                 </div>
                 <a><i class="fa-light fa-cart-shopping cart"></i></a>
                 <h4>R$19,99</h4>
                </div>
                
            </div>
```

Comment: how are you referencing the fontawesome library ?

Answer (score 2):

Have you included the Font-Awesome (6.2.1) CDN? In such a case, add it.

**To your Squarespace website page, add Font Awesome icons**

Go to Font Awesome and choose an icon you would like to add to your Squarespace website and copy the code.

For the rocket icon copy this code:

```
<i class="fas fa-rocket"></i>
```

You can copy this code to a code block on your Squarespace website.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
```

Comment: Its not a squarespace site, instead of showing the shopping cart icon its showing a squarespace "fa-light fa-cart-shopping cart"

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean:

```
 <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
```

?

Comment: [fa-light](https://fontawesome.com/v6/search?q=cart-sh&o=r&s=light) it's one of the available styles along with the most used one(`fa-solid`)